# Terraform dynamic block inside a nested block not passing in values

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am looking to use the google_os_config_guest_policies resource and am having issues with being able to pass in values to the nested block of code for `package_repositories`.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/os_config_guest_policies

Child module main.tf

```
package_repositories {
      dynamic "apt" {
        for_each = var.apt
        content {
          archive_type = lookup(apt.value, "archive_type", "abc")
          uri          = lookup(apt.value, "uri", "abc")
          distribution = lookup(apt.value, "distribution", null)
          components   = lookup(apt.value, "components", null)
          gpg_key      = lookup(apt.value, "gpg_key", null)
        }
      }
  }
```

Variables.tf

```
variable "apt" {
  description = "Variable used for the APT block supported in the package_repositories variable. Pass in variables for apt_archive_type, apt_components, apt_distribution, apt_uri, apt_gpg_key."
  type        = any
  default     = []
}
```

terraform.tfvars

```
apt = [
  {
    archive_type = "DEB"
    uri          = "https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt"
    distribution = "cloud-sdk-stretch"
    components       = ["main"]
  }
]
```

Whenever I try to pass in values from my tfvars I only get a blank `package_repositories` map passed in during my `terraform plan` step.

```
+ package_repositories { }
```

I have tried to remove the dynamic block and statically define the values for`package_repositories` which worked without any issues.

```
package_repositories {
    apt {
      archive_type = "DEB"
      uri          = "https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt"
      distribution = "cloud-sdk-stretch"
      components       = ["main"]
  }
}
```

If I try to rework my code to use the dynamic `apt` block it would try to pass in `null` values. Is there something wrong with syntax or is this due to being a beta resource where the dynamic block isn't working?

Comment: not sure this will change anything but have you tried adding `,` add the end of each element of the map in the `terraform.tfvars` file?

Comment: @LazyEval No luck there with putting a comma after each element of the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running it,  I got the desired output

```
     + package_repositories {
          + apt {
              + archive_type = "DEB"
              + components   = [
                  + "main",
                ]
              + distribution = "cloud-sdk-stretch"
              + uri          = "https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt"
            }
        }
```

Can u please confirm are you using `terraform.tfvars` or any other tfvars file. If other file , are u passing to your terraform plan using -var-file ?

Comment: Yes just using a terraform.tfvars file and it should be noticed by Terraform because I have other values in my .tfvars which are being used properly. Just to make sure you used a dynamic apt block and passed in values from your tfvars same as I did? I only ever saw your output when I hard-coded those values into my child module.

Comment: yes, code I used https://www.codepile.net/pile/w2YGev5b

Comment: Thanks for the help with troubleshooting. The code I had above was being used as a child module and I was using a secondary main.tf in a parent module to reference `source = ./modules/os-config` and forgot to put `apt = var.apt` in that secondary main.tf so it was never pulling in the tfvars values.